# Select a child element from a parent using a cousin node of the same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe Selectors to select elements. This is a complex nested scenario of cousin child.

Here is the HTML to get an idea of what I mentioned above:

[image: html]

In the picture, I have mentioned `1` and `2` which are the parent element (has same DOM) who has a grand grand child `path` and the same parent's grand grand child in the other tree is `<span title='John' /span>`. I need the node of the `path` but need to link `<span title='John' /span>` because all the parents have the same DOM.

I don't know how to resolve this situation using TestCafe. Do I have to use jQuery? If yes, then how? I tried a lot but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Sir, is it possible to copy/paste the html dom to actually understand the question ?

Comment: I can't paste the image. I thought I did but it isn't appearing. Let me try to quickly fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe API is smart enough to handle your case:

```
const JohnSelector = Selector('div.person-identity')
  .find('span.person-name')
  .withExactText('John');

const pathSelector = JohnSelector
  .parent('div.projects-project-role')
  .prevSibling('div.projects-project-role')
  .find('button svg path')
  .nth(1);

console.log(`${await JohnSelector.innerText}`);
console.log(`${await pathSelector.getAttribute("d")}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `jQuery` you can fetch all the elements with class `projects-project-role`, and then search each of those elements for a `path` tag and an element of the class `person-name`, and add their values to an array, like this:

```
var namePath = []; // initialize empty name/path array
$(".projects-project-role").each(function() {  // go through each element of class projects-project-role
    var path = $(this).find("path").attr("d"); // look for a path tag subelement and grab its d attribute
    var name = $(this).find(".person-name").text(); // look for an element of class person-name and grab its text
    namePath.push({path: path, name: name}); // add the gathered path and name to an array
});
console.log(namePath); // display the array
```

EDIT: Or in shorthand, and with `map`:

```
var namePath = $(".projects-project-role").get().map((p)=>({path: $(p).find('path').attr('d'), name: $(p).find('.person-name').text()}));
console.log(namePath); // display the array
```

Comment: this is also a solution but I am looking for TestCafe solution which I found more convenient.